# ColdFusion ValueList for dynamically named queries

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I've discovered that the `valuelist()` function doesn't like dynamically named queries:

```
<cfscript>
variables.nNumber = 1;
request.qDirectories = new query();
request.qDirectories.setDBType('query');
request.qDirectories.setAttributes(qDirectories=request.qAllDirectories);
request.qDirectories.setSQL("SELECT id, name, abbr, multiproperties, isPublished, 
                            isArchived, dateAdded, lastModified, lastModifiedBy, 
                            prefix, lstJournalCodes FROM qDirectories");
request["qDirectories#variables.nNumber#"] = request.qDirectories.execute().getResult();
writeDump(valueList(request["qDirectories#variables.nNumber#"].id));
</cfscript>
```

Upon discovering this, I thought `arrayToList()` would help.  It does help but it only brings back an array with one value in even if there are multiple rows.

Is there a way to get all the values from a particular column in a dynamically named query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copying/referencing the dynamic query to a simpler variable name doesn't help?  As in:

```
tempQry= request["qDirectories#variables.nNumber#"];

valueList(tempQry.id);
```

Comment: This answer works.  I had a similar problem a couple of years ago and hacked out a workaround.  Wish I'd thought of copying the query at the time.

Comment: Same principle can be applied to trying to do IsDefined() on a specific key within an array of structures

Comment: Perfect solution, completely overlooked copying the query to something non-dynamic.